# Receive all photos using pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Is it possible to save all received photos to folder via telegram bot? There is a method getFile (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile) but I don't know how to use it.

I'm using a python wrapper around the Telegram Bot API: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about saving your photos from chats, then it's not possible with Bot API, but I think it's possible with Telegram Core API and CLI Bots: [link](https://github.com/yagop/telegram-bot).

If you want to save all incoming files to bot, you can use [this](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/download_file_example.py) example from pyTelegramBotAPI dev.

Since photos also have `file_id`'s, you may try to use them in `getFile` method. Please, remember, that all photos are represented as array of copies of different `Width x Height` sizes.